# NameError: name 'guessesTaken' is not defined issue

Tags: python, python-3.x

Hi everybody I hope everybody is having a great day! I have been coding in python for about 6 months now and I have been working on this "guess my number code" and basically the computer choses a random number between 1-100 and then the user tries to guess it. I get a problem with my variable guessesTaken saying that is not defined but I clearly defined up on line 5.

Here is the code:

```
import random

def Loop():

  guessesTaken = 0

print('Hello! What is your name?')
myName = input()

number = random.randint(1, 100)
print('Hi, ' + myName + ', I am thinking of a number between 1 and 100.')

mod = number % 2
if mod > 0:
    print("The number I am thinking of is odd.")
else:
    print("The number I am thinking of is even.")


while guessesTaken < 10:
    print('Take a guess.')
    guess = input()
    guess = int(guess)

    guessesTaken = guessesTaken + 1

    if guess < number:
        print('Your guess is too low.') 

    if guess > number:
        print('Your guess is too high.')
        if guess == number:
          break

    if guess == number:
        print('Good job, ' + myName + '! You guessed my number in ' + str(guessesTaken) + ' guesses!')
        guessesTaken = 10




if guess != number:
  print('Nope. The number I was thinking of was ' + str(number))

  playagain = input('Would you like to play again')
  if playagain == "yes":
            Loop()
  if playagain == "no":
            print ( 'Goodbye :)')
            Loop()
```

I get the error "Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "python", line 20, in 
NameError: name 'guessesTaken' is not defined"

I have been trying to debug this for 1-2 weeks now and have still not found what is wrong with the code. **Please don't directly tell me what the problem is please just give my some hints or clues**

Sincerely yours Hardit a 6 month python programmer

Comment: Where is `guessesTaken` defined? Meaning what's its scope? https://docs.python.org/2/reference/executionmodel.html

Comment: Right after the def loop

Comment: As shown, `guessToken = 0` is the *only* thing in the function `Loop`. Fix your indentation.

Comment: But when I try to fix the indentation on guessTaken it always tells me to put it back to where it was

Comment: Your `Loop` function literally does nothing right now.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with **scoping** and (partially) initialization. **I suggest you look up how these things work, they are core concepts in programming.** 
The variable guessesTaken will be created "inside" the function loop, and will be available **ONLY** inside that function. 

Once the function returns, the scope changes and your variable is no longer in the scope (it cannot be "seen").

A quick fix is adding `guessesTaken = 0` in the same scope you want to use it. In this case, the scope is the whole file. Add the line `guessesTaken = 0` after your imports and you're done.

**Note:** Python is not strongly typed, you can have `whatever = 0` and then assign to `whatever` an Object of any type. In other languages, you have to assign to variables consistently with their types.

Comment: In my answer I did not take into account, as others have pointed out under you question, that your loop function does literally nothing (and, given my "fix", it will just reset your counter to 0).

Answer (score 0):

This error is there because in your code you initialize guessesTaken in the function Loop. However, you do not call the function so guessesTaken was not created yet. To make this work you have to call loop before the while loop. Or initialize guessesTaken outside the function.